# Figure label caption different for figure and figure index

Tags: floats, labels

I have a problem with a figure description. I already found how to put a legend part into a figure index, but below the figure the legend is in two row. How can I fix it in the same row but whiteout put all the text in figure index?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish,activeacute]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.bmp,.png,.pdf,.jpg}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, amsbsy}

%Figura 
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Combustion}
    \caption{Etapas de la combusti'on}{\textit{Adaptaci'on de Nussbaumer 1997} \cite{Nussbaumer1997}}
    \label{fig:Combustion}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, if this is what you want to achieve, but the following MWE yields the figure's caption with the citation in one line, while it excludes the italic text and the citation from the list of figures:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish,activeacute]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \caption[Etapas de la combusti'on]{Etapas de la combusti'on \textit{Adaptaci'on de Nussbaumer 1997} \cite{Nussbaumer1997}}
    \label{fig:Combustion}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Please note the `caption` command in the example:

```
\caption[<short version>]{<long version>}
```

The `<short version>` is used for the list of figures, while the `<long version>`  is placed below the image.